# if inside where query on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, where-clause

i have this query:

```
  def self.search(nombre,zona,tipoActividad,fechaInicio,fechaFin,nombreProfesor)

    where("nombre) iLIKE ? or contenido iLIKE ? or descripcion iLIKE ? ", "%#{nombre}%", "%#{nombre}%","%#{nombre}%")
      .where("lugar iLIKE ?", "%#{zona}%")
      .where("tipo_actividad iLIKE ?", "%#{tipoActividad}%")
      .where(['fecha_inicio >= ?', fechaInicio]) ***if !fechaInicio.blank?***
      .where(['fecha_fin <= ?', fechaFin]) ***if !fechaFin.blank?***
      .joins(:user).where("users.lastname iLIKE ?", "%#{nombreProfesor}%")
  end
```

I have the problem when i have to filter by fecha_fin and fecha_inicio. i need to filter by them only if the parameters are present. How can I re-change the query yo be ok?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your `self.search` method is building and returning a chain of relation operations.

So you'll need to store the logic in a variable, add to the chain as needed, and then return the relation.

```
def self.search(nombre, zona, tipo_actividad, fecha_inicio, fecha_fin, nombre_profesor)
  relation = where("nombre) iLIKE ? or contenido iLIKE ? or descripcion iLIKE ? ", "%#{nombre}%", "%#{nombre}%","%#{nombre}%")
            .where("lugar iLIKE ?", "%#{zona}%")
            .where("tipo_actividad iLIKE ?", "%#{tipo_actividad}%")

  relation = relation.where('fecha_inicio >= ?', fecha_inicio) if fecha_inicio.present?
  relation = relation.where('fecha_fin <= ?', fecha_fin) if fecha_fin.present?

  relation = relation.joins(:user).where("users.lastname iLIKE ?", "%#{nombreProfesor}%")

  return relation
end
```